# source control tool for jsp and aspx files

Tags: version-control

My team work on both type of projects i.e. jsp projects and aspx projects and While evaluating TFS as source version tool both i found out that it does not support versioning of jsp files.

Im looking for a tool which may support both type of project files.

Any open source tool which may server the purpose?

Pls advice

Comment: Why are you saying that TFS doesn't support versioning of JSP files? They are text files.

Comment: Git, subversion, CVS, ... But tfs should be able to do the same